# Saving Random string

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

Following is my function to save user registration details:

```
createAdminAccount(firstName: string, lastName: string, customerEmail: string, customerMobile: string, password: string, termsAccepted: boolean, date = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP): Promise<any>{
return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(customerEmail, password)
  .then( newUser => {
    this.afDatabase.object(`/userProfile/${newUser.uid}`)
      .set({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        customerEmail,
        termsAccepted,
        customerId: newUser.uid,            
        customerAdmin: true,
        date,
        hcn: this.hcn(),
    }).then(() =>{
      ??
    })

  }, error => { console.error(error); });
```

}

I want to save 'same' generated the Random number for reference. Following is my code generating random number:

```
hcn(){
var d = new Date().getTime();
var hcNumber = 'hcn-xxxx-yxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
  var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
  d = Math.floor(d / 16);
  return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
});
return hcNumber;
```

The step of `hcn: this.hcn()` generates a random number(in the first mention above) but when I want to save the same `hcn: this.hcn()` it generates another random number... I want to save the same random number as in the first loop.

I want to make the first `this.hcn()` available in global scope to use it again and save under separate list

Just can't figure out :(

Comment: I see you are calling it only once, where's the problem?

Comment: The question mark `??` is when I am calling second time but gives me different random number

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to generate a new random string, then you should only call it once in your app!

In this code snippet

```
//more code here
this.afDatabase.object(`/userProfile/${newUser.uid}`)
      .set({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        customerEmail,
        termsAccepted,
        customerId: newUser.uid,            
        customerAdmin: true,
        date,
        hcn: this.hcn(), <--------------
    }).then(() =>{

//more code here
```

Don't do it that way, you are calling a function  thus creating a new random string.

Possible solution is to save the random string in a variable via your constructor

```
myRandomString: string;

constructor(){
this.myRandomString = this.hcn();
}
```

Then use it in your previous code

```
this.afDatabase.object(`/userProfile/${newUser.uid}`)
      .set({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        customerEmail,
        termsAccepted,
        customerId: newUser.uid,            
        customerAdmin: true,
        date,
        hcn: this.myRandomString,
    }).then(() =>{
```

Comment: the `hcn` is still undefined... I think it's because of `myRandomString: string`

Comment: it should not be undefined because if you are doing this `this.myRandomString = this.hcn();` unless there's something wrong with your function

Comment: Yup... I was calling `hcn()` after the register function. Got it sorted. Thanks brother